# Plotting two-variable function as function of one variable with manipulate for both variables

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I have a function g(x,y) and would like to plot it as g(x) with a slider to vary y. What I currently have is a g(x,y) plotted as g(x) but with y as a parameter which I can adjust:

```
Manipulate[Plot[g[x,y],{x,0,10}],{y,0,10}]
```

That works fine, but now I'd like to be able to vary the upper value of the x-axis so that we can adjust how much of the graph we see (or how much of the x-axis we see). This is what I've tried (but didn't work):

```
Manipulate[Plot[g[x,y],{x,0,Manipulate[x,{x,0.1,10}]}],{y,0,10}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
g[x_, y_] := Sin[y x] 
Manipulate[Plot[g[x,y],{x,0,xmax}],{y,0,10},{{xmax,10},1,30}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot - what does the 10 in {xmax, 10} do?

Comment: @tukmajerb, it defines the initial value. You should  read the documentation, it is really good. Highlight `Manipulate` and press F1.